# esp8266 & TFT_eSPI : how can i avoid alignment exception when drawing an image?

Tags: exception, alignment, esp8266

I am working with the Bodmer TFT_eSPI library. The example to show bitmap drawing works (TFT_Flash_Bitmap), but integrating that code in my app consistently produces ESP exception 9 : memory alignment exception.

Commenting out the pushColors() or pushColor() calls avoids the crash so I suspect it's happening in there.

I assume the error is all mine. Can anyone help me find the cause/solution ?

Thanks,

Danny

```
Exception (9):
epc1=0x402071fc epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000001 depc=0x00000000


/*
 * Note the Bodmer version of drawIcon is for FLASH memory. No such thing here.
 * See TFT_eSPI/examples/320 x 240/TFT_Flash_Bitmap , moved from example to class method here.
 */
void Oled::drawIcon(const uint16_t *icon, int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t width, uint16_t height) {
#if 0
  uint16_t pixbuf[OLED_BS];

  setWindow(x, y, x + width - 1, y + height - 1);

  // How many whole buffers to send ?
  uint16_t nb = ((uint16_t)height * width) / OLED_BS;

  // Fill and send that many buffers to TFT
  for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < OLED_BS; j++) {
      pixbuf[j] = icon[i * OLED_BS + j];
    }

    // pushColors(pixbuf, OLED_BS);
  }

  // How many pixels not yet sent ?
  uint16_t np = ((uint16_t)height * width) % OLED_BS;

  // Send any partial buffer left over
  if (np) {
    for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
      pixbuf[i] = icon[nb * OLED_BS + i];

      // pushColors(pixbuf, np);
    }
#else
  setWindow(x, y, x + width - 1, y + height - 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
      ; // pushColor(icon[i]);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#else`
`#endif`  - I guess you use it for debug?

Check size of icon array, you try to read `icon[i * OLED_BS + j]`, I guess in some cases you can have problems.

Comment: Grmbl, I was calculating what you meant and I didn't believe you.
Until I saw that I didn't return the allocated array in another function.

Thanks for pointing me to that.